# "break" não termina a execução como deveria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, break

> Crie um programa onde o usuário possa digitar vários valores numéricos e cadastre-os em uma lista. Caso o número já exista lá dentro, ele não será adicionado. No final, serão exibidos todos os valores únicos digitados, em ordem crescente.

E até ai tudo bem essa foi a minha solução:

```
lista= []
     while True:
         ad = (int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
         if ad not in lista:
             lista.append(ad)
             print('Adicionado com sucesso!')
         else:
             print('Valor duplicado. Adição negada.')
         ask = str(input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0]
         while ask not in 'SN':
             if ask == 'S':
                 continue
             elif ask == 'N':
                 break
             elif ask != 'SN':
                 print('Resposta inválida, por favor escolha entre [S/N]')
                 while ask not in 'SN':
                    ask = str(input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0]
print('-=' * 30)
lista.sort()
print(f'Voce digitou os números: {lista}')
```

Quando perguntado se quero continuar e eu respondo 'N' o programa segue funcionando sem dar o `break`. Entretanto o mesmo código no PyCharm de outro colega funciona sem problema nenhum.

O que pode ser isso? Um *bug*? É possível resolvê-lo?

Comment: `ask` só pode ser `'S'` ou `'N'`, mas você usa a condição `while ask not in 'SN'`. Algo errado não está certo.

Answer (score 8):

Não, não é bug no PyCharm, muito menos funciona no computador do seu colega. Não funciona porque o código está errado.

Primeiro, indentação. A indentação define os blocos de código no Python e é **fundamental** que ela esteja correta. Diferente da maioria das linguagens, o código não funcionará com a indentação errada. Seu primeiro laço está indentado em relação à definição da variável na primeira linha e isso não pode. Ambos devem estar no mesmo nível:

```
lista = []
while True:
    ...
```

Segundo, a função `input` **sempre** retorna uma *string*, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e completamente desnecessário. Você remove os espaços do valor lido, converte para maiúsculas e pega o primeiro caractere:

```
lista= []
while True:
    ad = (int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
    if ad not in lista:
        lista.append(ad)
        print('Adicionado com sucesso!')
    else:
        print('Valor duplicado. Adição negada.')
    ask = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]
```

Terceiro, você espera que o usuário digite apenas S ou N, mas na linha abaixo você faz:

```
lista= []
while True:
    ad = (int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
    if ad not in lista:
        lista.append(ad)
        print('Adicionado com sucesso!')
    else:
        print('Valor duplicado. Adição negada.')
    ask = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ').strip().upper()[0]
    while ask not in 'SN':
        ...
```

Enquanto `ask` **não for** S ou N, faça... e logo depois você verifica se é S ou N. Essas condições nunca serão satisfeitas uma vez que o `while` garante que `ask` é **diferente** de S e N. Usar o `continue` ou o `break` aqui também não faz sentido, pois eles atuarão sobre o último laço de repetição, que é justamente o `while ask not in 'SN'`, mas isso não faz sentido.

Quarto, a sua última condição `elif ask != 'SN'` também está errada. Se você garantiu que `ask` é somente o **primeiro caractere informado**, ele nunca possuirá dois caracteres, portanto a igualdade **sempre** será satisfeita.

---

Melhorias:

1. Use `set` no lugar de `list`; ele, por definição, não possui valores duplicados;
2. Trate a exceção lançada por `int` quando a conversão para inteiro falhar;
3. Você pode parar a leitura quando o usuário informar algo que não seja um número;

Por exemplo:

```
numeros = set()

while True:
    try:
        numero = int(input('Número? '))
        numeros.add(numero)
    except ValueError:
        break

print('Ordem crescente: ', sorted(numeros))
```

Ficando:

```
Número? 5
Número? 3
Número? 4
Número? 8
Número? 1
Número? 9
Número?
Ordem crescente:  [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 6):

Certamente não porque o PyCharm é só um editor de código. E também não é no Python, porque duas coisas exatamente iguais só podem dar o mesmo resultado, mesmo que tivesse um *bug*. *bugs* não são mágicos que aparecem e desaparecem. Mas se não é tudo exatamente igual, aí pode dar resultado diferente, e não dá para culpar o IDE pelo problema, o problema está no que é diferente, ou seja, seu código, sua configuração. De qualquer forma, milhões de pessoas usam Python há anos, quais as chances que você teria de achar um *bug* em um código bem básico logo no começo do seu aprendizado? Não parece mais óbvio que seja um problema no seu código e que deveria partir dessa premissa antes de pensar em *bug* de uma ferramenta consagrada?

Eu fui tentar compilar, dava erro, eu consertava, dava outro, eu consertava e dava outro, até que eu desisti de tentar.

De qualquer forma eu vi alguns problemas conceituais no código e pelo menos um de lógica que causa todo o problema. Se você cria dois laços aninhados e no mais interno dá um `break` nele, para onde acha que ele vai? Para o final desse laço. Imagino que está achando que ele sai dos dois laços, mas não é o caso. Além disto está criando mais um terceiro e repetindo as mesmas coisas que já havia programado antes. Não só isto, uma condição testa se é S ou N, depois testa-as individualmente e depois se não é nenhuma das duas, isto não faz sentido.

Assim é mais simples, mais organizado e funciona:

```
def entrada(lista):
    while True:
        ad = (int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
        if ad not in lista:
            lista.append(ad)
            print('Adicionado com sucesso!')
        else:
            print('Valor duplicado. Adição negada.')
        while True:
            ask = str(input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0]
            if ask == 'S':
                break
            elif ask == 'N':
                return
lista = []
entrada(lista)
print(lista)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Dl2MVx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/giylcfon-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/WhileBreak.py).

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o PyCharm só executa, através do Python, o que você fez, então, o erro está no código.

O primeiro erro que ocorre é: se o usuário digitar corretamente `'S'` ou `'N'`, ele nunca vai entrar no `while ask not in 'SN'`, pois, essa condição significa: *enquanto "ask" não estiver em 'SN'*. Ou seja, `ask` estará dentro de `'SN'`, logo, a condição não é verdadeira, e ele não entra no `while`.

O outro erro é: se `ask` realmente não estiver em `'SN'`, então, ele não passará nas primeira e segunda condições dentro do segundo `while`, pois:

- `ask` não será igual a `'S'`
- `ask` também não será igual a `'N'`

Mas, `ask` será diferente de `'SN'`, então ele irá imprimir o aviso, e começará isso tudo de novo.

Então, você primeiro tem que testar se `ask` é igual a `'S'`, ou igual a `'N'`, antes de executar o `while`. E, se entrar no `while`, você faz a pergunta novamente, atribuindo a nova resposta para `ask`.

No entanto, após isso, você deverá criar uma forma de saber se a resposta "interna" foi **não** (ou `'N'`), pois, o `break` que você executa dentro do segundo `while` só fará o mesmo parar, mas o primeiro `while`, que é o `while True`, continuará.

Tendo tudo isso em mente, acho que você poderia fazer desse modo:

```
lista= []
while True:
    ad = (int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
    if ad not in lista:
        lista.append(ad)
        print('Adicionado com sucesso!')
    else:
        print('Valor duplicado. Adição negada.')
    ask = str(input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0]
    if ask == 'N':
        break
    resposta = None
    while ask not in 'SN':
        ask = str(input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0]
        if ask == 'S':
            break
        elif ask == 'N':
            resposta = ask
            break
    if resposta == 'N':
        break
print('-=' * 30)
lista.sort()
print(f'Voce digitou os números: {lista}')
```

Espero ter ajudado!