# Colocar só True e False em if e while

Tags: python, if, while, booleano

Queria saber para que isso serve:

```
if true:
  #Código
```

ou

```
if false:
  #Código
```

ou

```
while true:
  #código
```

etc.

Comment: Comece fazendo o [tour] então, lá ensina o básico do funcionamento do site. Pode acessar a [help] também para ir mais a fundo.

Answer (score 7):

Vou partir do princípio que usou com maiúsculo, porque em minúsculo ou não funciona, ou então está usando variáveis chamadas `true` ou `false`, que são nomes um pouco ruins para variáveis.

Estritamente os primeiros servem para nada. O primeiro entrará no bloco do `if` todas as vezes, o segundo nunca entrará, então não tem porque usar aquilo. Pode ser usado momentaneamente para um teste, mas provavelmente teria um comentário junto com a condição real.

Algumas pessoas usam o `False` para fazer que um trecho não seja executado momentaneamente, isso não costuma ser uma boa ideia e pode ser resolvido com comentário no códigos, isso é chamado *comment out*. Em essência os dois primeiros não deveriam ser usados em código real.

O terceiro pode ser mais útil dependendo do código que está ali dentro. Você entre em um laço de repetição de qualquer jeito e dentro terá um `if` que fará ele sair. Isso é útil para manter o código mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Se você tiver um condição no meio do bloco código que faz sair do laço e essa seria a mesma condição do `while`, então teria uma repetição indesejada porque teria duas vezes o mesmo código que precisam estar sincronizados sempre, violando o DRY e tornando a manutenção mais complicada e arriscada, então prefere-se só ter a condição no meio e o laço se torna "infinito" (não que ele seja de fato).

Se não tem essa saída no meio do bloco, ou seja, só deve sair em condição no início dele, ou se as condições do laço e interno são diferentes aí não tem motivo para fazer isto. Como Python não tem um `do...while` pode-se usar um `while True` para simular o `do`, aí um `if` no final do bloco faz a saída, fazendo que a verificação seja sempre no fim do bloco e não no começo, como é no `while` normal.

Em outros locais, e principais em funções pode ser outro motivo para usar `true` ou `false` não posso falar sem um contexto.

Tem um [exemplo em pergunta que eu respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/352409/101) que demonstra este tipo de uso:

```
def entrada(lista):
    while True:
        ad = (int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
        if ad not in lista:
            lista.append(ad)
            print('Adicionado com sucesso!')
        else:
            print('Valor duplicado. Adição negada.')
        while True:
            ask = str(input('Deseja continuar?[S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0]
            if ask == 'S':
                break
            elif ask == 'N':
                return
lista = []
entrada(lista)
print(lista)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/IfElse.py).

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, Python diferencia letras maiúsculas de minúsculas, portanto `true` é diferente de `True`. No Python, existem os valores `True` e `False`, mas não existe `true` e `false`; no seus exemplos daria erro indicando nomes não definidos.

Vamos supor, então, que seja `True` e `False`.

> ```
> if True:
>     print('Executei')
> ```

Não tem função alguma. A estrutura condicional serve para executar um determinado bloco de código somente quando a condição é satisfeita; se a condição sempre é verdadeira, o bloco **sempre será** executado e, portanto, não faz sentido ter a condição.

Assim, o código equivalente sem a estrutura condicional seria:

```
print('Executei')
```

> ```
> if False:
>     print('Executei')
> ```

Não tem função alguma. Ao contrário da situação acima, quando a condição sempre é falsa, o bloco de código **nunca será** executado; se nunca é executado, para que mantê-lo no arquivo? Qualquer estrutura semelhante a essa pode ser removida do arquivo fonte sem efeitos colaterais.

> ```
> while True:
>     print('Executei')
> ```

Essa pode ter alguma utilidade, dependendo do contexto. O `while` define uma estrutura de laço de repetição que executa o bloco de código **enquanto** a condição é satisfeita. Neste caso particular, a condição **sempre é** satisfeita, portanto é o que chamamos de laço infinito. Seu programa irá rodar infinitamente, salvo os casos em que é parado via estimulo externo ou quando a expressão `break` é executada dentro do laço.

Um exemplo disso é solicitar ao usuário do programa um valor inteiro entre 0 e 10; enquanto ele não informar um valor válido, apresentar uma mensagem e solicitar novamente. Como não sabemos quantas tentativas isso demandará, fazemos um laço infinito:

```
while True:
    try:
        nota = int(input("Informe a nota entre 0 e 10: "))
        if not 0 <= nota <= 10:
            raise ValueError("Nota fora da faixa permitida")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Valor inválido:", e)
    else:
        break

print(nota)
```

Vide [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/5878).

Answer (score -2):

Não tem um função muito útil.
A não ser que vc tenha uma programa com uma aplicação muito específica, como um programa que vai executar um while sem parar e vai morrer apenas com a sua intervenção, não com a de um user propriamente dito.

Maaaaas, ao meu ver, não é também um jeito muito pythonico de se trabalhar.
No caso do "if" é pior ainda, não é necessário criar uma estrutura de condicional se a condição será sempre verdadeira ou falsa, apenas codifique sequencialmente.

Como dito anteriormente pelos colegas, talvez em um contexto de teste seja válido mas fora disso não vejo muita aplicação.